# Arabic Language is out of DIV Block Container in Wordpress

Tags: html, css, right-to-left

I am using avada theme and recently added some arabic in a page and it seem off, Its is overflowing out of the div container and i am unable to fix it..
is there any fix kindly let me know

also the div who is holding paragraph tags is set to direction: 'rtl' already.

Comment: try this  style .post-content {  word-wrap: break-word;}

Comment: Awesome, thank you @vel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.post-content { 
    word-wrap: break-word;
 }
```